# How to pass path to xargs command in Linux

Tags: bash, grep, ls, xargs, tail

I have the following code, which removes old files in a directory based on their timestamps:

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
```

I am trying to make an executable script out of this and I don't want to cd into the directory where the above command should be run, but rather simply pass the path e.g. `/tmp/backups/` to it.

How would I do this? Attaching the path directly after each command `ls`, `grep`, `tail`, `xargs` and `rm` ?

Comment: You should probably [not be using `ls` in the first place](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The script itself can safely `cd` to the directory you pass in as an argument; the parent shell's working directory will not be affected.

Comment: To remove older than 3 days:
`find <path> -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;`
or
`find <path> -mtime +3 -delete;`

Comment: @SielaQ But I want to keep only and only the most recent file.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, but my files have a static pattern which are not affected by the problem you mentioned. And passing the path to `ls` didn't work for me. It still looked in the parent directory.

Comment: I didn't say pass the path to `ls`; I said `cd`, just like the answer you got. `ls` is affected by a number of problems, including but not limited to mangling special characters in file names into a question mark or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your path is the first parameter of your script, you could do a

```
cd "${1:-/tmp/backups}" # Use the parameter, supply default if none
# Do your cleanup here
```

If you have afterwards more stuff to do in the original working directory, just do a

```
cd - >/dev/null
# Do what ever you need to do in the original working directory
```

The sole purpose of the redirection of stdout into the bit bucket is, because `cd -` by default prints to stdout the directory it changes into.